# IIO Unable to refill buffer: Connection timed out (110) error when running iio_readdev

Tags: embedded, yocto, iio

I have made a custom Linux image with Yocto for use with [CN0540](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0540.html#rd-overview) and DE10-Nano. The manufacturer of the CN0540 (Analog Devices) provides an [evaluation image](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0540/de10-nano) for the board, which works without issue, however in my custom image which is using the same kernel fork ([ADI Linux fork](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux)), the same defconfig as far as I can tell (socfpga_adi_defconfig), and the same device tree ([CN0540 dts](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/socfpga_cyclone5_de10_nano_cn0540.dts)), and also the same HDL is loaded on the FPGA ([CN0540 HDL](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0540/hdl)) I can't use the buffer from the ADC on the CN0540 (AD7768-1). I can read a single value from the ADC, either with libiio's `iio_info` command, or with the device file at `sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage0_raw`, but I can't read from the buffer of the device E.g `iio_readdev ad7768-1` returns `Unable to refill buffer: Connection timed out (110)`, or doing

```
> echo 1 > scan_elements/in_voltage0_en
> echo 1 > buffer/enable
> cat /dev/iio:device0 | hexdump
```

which causes the device to crash, unless I set the length of the buffer to 1 with `echo 1 > buffer/length` which causes the device to output

```
[  441.310599] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
[  441.316258] rcu:     0-....: (2099 ticks this GP) idle=10f/1/0x40000002 softirq=2509/2509 fqs=1033
[  441.325163]  (t=2100 jiffies g=497 q=7)
[  441.329057] NMI backtrace for cpu 0
[  441.332592] CPU: 0 PID: 163 Comm: cat Not tainted 5.15.0-yocto-standard-adi #1
[  441.339927] Hardware name: Altera SOCFPGA
[  441.343988] Backtrace:
[  441.346453] [<c0d914b0>] (dump_backtrace) from [<c0d916fc>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[  441.354073]  r7:c010edfc r6:00000000 r5:60070193 r4:c143b218
[  441.359801] [<c0d916dc>] (show_stack) from [<c0d94ecc>] (dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x54)
[  441.367360] [<c0d94e84>] (dump_stack_lvl) from [<c0d94ef0>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
[  441.374907]  r5:00000000 r4:20070193
[  441.378525] [<c0d94ed8>] (dump_stack) from [<c05850fc>] (nmi_cpu_backtrace+0xe0/0x114)
[  441.386424] [<c058501c>] (nmi_cpu_backtrace) from [<c0585218>] (nmi_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0xe8/0x134)
[  441.395965]  r7:c010edfc r6:c0e01ee4 r5:c170469c r4:00000000
[  441.401597] [<c0585130>] (nmi_trigger_cpumask_backtrace) from [<c010fd68>] (arch_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0x20/0x24)
[  441.412180]  r9:c1703f10 r8:c0e01ee0 r7:c1835438 r6:00000000 r5:c1703fa4 r4:c171e840
[  441.419886] [<c010fd48>] (arch_trigger_cpumask_backtrace) from [<c0d9340c>] (rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0x144/0x174)
[  441.429922] [<c0d932c8>] (rcu_dump_cpu_stacks) from [<c0198490>] (rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x6a8/0xa58)
[  441.438860]  r10:2e138000 r9:c1702d00 r8:c1693f40 r7:c18361a0 r6:00000000 r5:ef7cbf40
[  441.446784]  r4:c171e840
[  441.449304] [<c0197de8>] (rcu_sched_clock_irq) from [<c01a354c>] (update_process_times+0x98/0xc4)
[  441.458174]  r10:c1702d80 r9:c1702d40 r8:c184fd40 r7:2e138000 r6:c1702d00 r5:00000000
[  441.465969]  r4:ef7c5540
[  441.468524] [<c01a34b4>] (update_process_times) from [<c01b74e0>] (tick_sched_timer+0x88/0x2d8)
[  441.477198]  r7:c1ea9dc0 r6:00000066 r5:bf87a4da r4:ef7c6128
[  441.482830] [<c01b7458>] (tick_sched_timer) from [<c01a4260>] (__hrtimer_run_queues+0x1fc/0x36c)
[  441.491730]  r10:ef7c5e14 r9:ef7c6128 r8:20070193 r7:00000000 r6:c01b7458 r5:ef7c5dc0
[  441.499645]  r4:ef7c5e00
[  441.502183] [<c01a4064>] (__hrtimer_run_queues) from [<c01a5158>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x13c/0x2c8)
[  441.511041]  r10:ef7c5e98 r9:ef7c5e70 r8:ef7c5e48 r7:ef7c5dcc r6:00000003 r5:20070193
[  441.518836]  r4:ef7c5dc0
[  441.521357] [<c01a501c>] (hrtimer_interrupt) from [<c0110744>] (twd_handler+0x44/0x4c)
[  441.529394]  r10:c1ea8000 r9:c1ea9dc0 r8:f080210c r7:c1d08240 r6:00000018 r5:c17046b4
[  441.537301]  r4:00000001
[  441.539821] [<c0110700>] (twd_handler) from [<c01838c8>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x9c/0x200)
[  441.548321]  r5:c17046b4 r4:c1d09000
[  441.551888] [<c018382c>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq) from [<c017ced4>] (handle_domain_irq+0x6c/0x88)
[  441.560961]  r7:0000001d r6:00000000 r5:00000000 r4:c1692a14
[  441.566593] [<c017ce68>] (handle_domain_irq) from [<c0101300>] (gic_handle_irq+0x88/0x9c)
[  441.574767]  r7:c1692a20 r6:f0802100 r5:c177a344 r4:c17046b4
[  441.580494] [<c0101278>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<c0100afc>] (__irq_svc+0x5c/0x78)
[  441.587952] Exception stack(0xc1ea9dc0 to 0xc1ea9e08)
[  441.593047] 9dc0: c28b3700 00000000 00000000 00000003 00001000 c28b3700 c2b47f40 befe9c04
[  441.601193] 9de0: c28b3774 befe9c04 c1ea8000 c1ea9e24 c1ea9e28 c1ea9e10 c0a95530 c0a949ac
[  441.609342] 9e00: 20070013 ffffffff
[  441.612863]  r9:c1ea8000 r8:c28b3774 r7:c1ea9df4 r6:ffffffff r5:20070013 r4:c0a949ac
[  441.620699] [<c0a949a0>] (iio_dma_buffer_dequeue) from [<c0a95530>] (iio_dma_buffer_read+0x148/0x19c)
[  441.629894]  r5:c28b3700 r4:00001000
[  441.633452] [<c0a953e8>] (iio_dma_buffer_read) from [<c0952618>] (iio_buffer_read+0x178/0x228)
[  441.642168]  r10:c1ea8000 r9:befe9c04 r8:00001000 r7:00000400 r6:00000002 r5:c1e43000
[  441.649962]  r4:c28b3700
[  441.652483] [<c09524a0>] (iio_buffer_read) from [<c0954b24>] (iio_buffer_read_wrapper+0x2c/0x38)
[  441.661248]  r10:00000003 r9:c0954af8 r8:00001000 r7:00000001 r6:c1ea8000 r5:c1ea9f60
[  441.669050]  r4:c2b28540
[  441.671571] [<c0954af8>] (iio_buffer_read_wrapper) from [<c02b2da8>] (vfs_read+0xc4/0x320)
[  441.679817] [<c02b2ce4>] (vfs_read) from [<c02b348c>] (ksys_read+0x74/0xec)
[  441.686766]  r10:00000003 r9:00000000 r8:00000000 r7:befe9c04 r6:c1ea8000 r5:c2b28540
[  441.694560]  r4:c2b28540
[  441.697081] [<c02b3418>] (ksys_read) from [<c02b351c>] (sys_read+0x18/0x1c)
[  441.704027]  r9:c1ea8000 r8:c0100244 r7:00000003 r6:b6f681a0 r5:befe9c04 r4:00001000
[  441.711733] [<c02b3504>] (sys_read) from [<c0100060>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
[  441.719310] Exception stack(0xc1ea9fa8 to 0xc1ea9ff0)
[  441.724344] 9fa0:                   00001000 befe9c04 00000003 befe9c04 00001000 00000000
[  441.732488] 9fc0: 00001000 befe9c04 b6f681a0 00000003 00000000 01000000 00000003 befe9c04
[  441.740769] 9fe0: 00000003 befe9bb8 b6e6070f b6de1ae6
```

and that output repeats every ~20 seconds.

The device is supposed to send an interrupt to the OS when the buffer is ready, so I probed the DRDY pin (which is the pin for the interrupt) of the device with an MCU, and the pin never goes high.

I also tried switching the libiio version I was using to the same as the evaluation image, 0.23 to 0.21 and the error when running `iio_readdev ad7768-1` changed from `Unable to refill buffer: Connection timed out (110)` to

```
Unable to refill buffer: Connection timed out
ERROR: Error during buffer disable: No such file or directory
```

which I'm pretty sure is functionally the same error, so I changed the libiio version back to 0.23

I patched the device driver and libiio in an attempt to find the problem and found out that the problem line from calling `iio_readdev ad7768-1` in libiio is [this one](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/blob/690ab5a7ce3841197905f8dd42f78083ca9cb7ff/local.c#L291)  `ret = poll(pollfd, 2, timeout_rel);`, and the problem function in the device driver seems to be [this one](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux/blob/c1f4b28e0f0a816a90956b4e85a07daae4f8ad97/drivers/iio/adc/ad7768-1.c#L801) `hw_submit_block`.

What is causing the timed out error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found a solution.

U-boot needed to have some handoff files generated.

```bash
$ python ./arch/arm/mach-socfpga/cv_bsp_generator/cv_bsp_generator.py \
          -i <path_to_qpds_handoff>/hps_isw_handoff/soc_system_hps_0 \
          -o board/altera/cyclone5-socdk/qts/
```

Docs for this are in the [/doc/README.socfpga](https://github.com/altera-opensource/u-boot-socfpga/blob/socfpga_v2023.01/doc/README.socfpga#L107) file.